# laravel routing returning 404 without using index.php

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I am having a small issue creating a dynamic sitemap.xml for the site.

**My routing file:**

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml', [
    'uses' => 'PageController@sitemapXml',
    'as'   => 'user.page.sitemapxml'
]);
```

**My controller:**

```
public function sitemapXml(){
        ....
        $content .= '</urlset>';
        return response($content, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

**My issue:**
To access get the correct response i have to use the following route:
www.mysite.com/**index.php**/sitemap.xml
However, if i do www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml, i get a 404. 
If i manually add the sitemap.xml file in my public folder, i can access the file i just added, but not the dynamic one created in my controller.

**My research:**
Its probably a problem with the server and not laravel itself. Apparently, .xml extension are not processed through the normal routing. 
It suggests adding:

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

that did not work.

I also tried the changing my .htaccess to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

as specified in the docs

**My question:** 
Is their anything I can do laravel-wise to handle .xml requests?

Also, if you could guide me towards anything that might help me understand this process better, its very welcomed.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help

**UPDATE:** 
if instead of using my localhost, i use "php artisan serve", things work correctly without any issue.

Comment: It is possible that your webserver is choosing to handle that route differently because it has an extension of xml. However to note: This is very much webserver specific so it would help if we knew which one you were using (since you tried to alter files supplied for both nginx and apache)

Comment: I am on an apache server, Ubuntu 14.04. I've come across "nginx" a lot while looking for an answer. I'll have to look more into that because I have no idea what it refers to. in my etc file, I find no nginx folder btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this link:
https://laravel.io/forum/09-15-2015-removing-indexphp-from-url-laravel-5116

I changed my .conf file and voila.

Hope this helps you

Just to clarify: Nothing wrong with Laravel. More server specific.